# `#parent span` style is overriding the `.child span` style

Tags: html, css

I have a case where I have a `.menu` within a `#header` and when I accessed `.menu`'s children via a css selector like `.menu a`, it is using the `#header a` instead.

I was expecting the `.menu a` to override the `#header a` as it is closer to the `a` element. Why isn't this happening? I'm assuming it has with it being a class compared to an id based on the example below.

In the example, is there a good way override `#red span` css within `.blue span` without otherwise restricting the parent style?

By "good way" I suppose I mean flexible. For example `.blue` could be an element created by a php framework that is used in many places (possibly not within an id styled parent element, or possibly within a parent styled on a different id).

Here is an [**example**](http://jsfiddle.net/f4ke2/2/). All except `#green` will still be red:

HTML:

```
<div id="red">
    <span>red</span>
    <div class="blue">
        <span>blue(class) - should be blue</span>
    </div>
    <div id="green">
        <span>green(id) - should be green</span>
    </div>
    <div class="green">
        <span>green(class) - should be green</span>
    </div>
    <div>
        <span>no child div style - should still be red</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#red span {
    color: red;
}
.blue span {
    color: blue;
}
.green, #green span {
    color: green;
}
```

Comment: Based on answers (although helpful - I've given `+1`'s) and what I've seen elsewhere... it seems there isn't a practical solution to do this with the flexibility I was looking for without changing the DOM or using `!important`. I'll just have to find ways to work around this CSS "feature", in my current scenario I think I'll add a class to the parent and style off that instead of the ID.

Comment: The first two paragraphs describe a scenario other than otherwise presented in the question. The question title is misleading, as this is not about “parent style” overriding anything.

Comment: @smerny check new addition to my answer.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela, the style based off the parent (`#header a`) is being applied instead of the style based off the child (`.menu a`). I was wanting the style based off the nearer (`.menu`) element to control the styling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The priority of applying a CSS rule (without `!important`) is:

1. Number of IDs in the selector. If draw,
2. Number of attributes and classes. If draw,
3. names or pseudo-elements. If draw,
4. last declaration on the CSS file. This, of course, never draws.

Since `#red span` has an ID, and `.green` doesn't have any, `#red span` applies.

For further explanation of which CSS rule is apply first, check this [nice article on smashing magazine](http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/)

To work around, you can [use a more specific rule](http://jsfiddle.net/f4ke2/6/). This way it gets tie on number one, but since it have extra classes, your rule wins due the number two.

Comment: Thanks for the list, but this doesn't really attempt to solve my issue... although it sounds like it may be impossible to do what I want with the given dom :(

Comment: @smerney if you don't/can't modify the red part, the only way to accomplish this is by using "important" or by setting the color using at least one ID on the CSS rule (like changing the class by an ID)

Comment: That [**appears**](http://jsfiddle.net/f4ke2/4/) to work fine. Was hoping to avoid that but may actually go that way.

Comment: @smerny I forgot this and when I entered in your js fiddle I have an idea. Check the update on my answer

Answer (score 1):

Selector specificity dictates that id had priority over class. Even though the blue class is after red in the Cascade,  red takes priority because of specificity. You can use the Selector `#red .blue span` if needed

Comment: What if `.blue` is a commonly used element in a php framework and it is not always in `#red` (may even be within another element styled by id)? Is there a flexible way to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow this color metaphor in the right way, but I think you can achieve what you are asking for with:

Comment: @smerny it's advisable to avoid the I'd selector for this reason

Comment: CakePHP's default css uses an ID selector to style the `#header`, do you suggest it is better to add a class to `#header` and other similar elements and style off that instead?

Comment: @smerny not necessarily better but it sounds like toy don't have many options

Comment: Well thanks for the suggestions, I suppose I'll figure something out based on them although it wasn't quite what I hoped for (which I guess may be impossible with the curent dom).

Answer (score 1):

the simplest and cleanest:

http://jsfiddle.net/f4ke2/7/

```
#red {
    color: red;
}
.blue span {
    color: blue;
}
.green, #green span {
    color: green;
}
```

OR What if you do this? :)

```
#red > span {
    color: red;
}
```

OR

```
 #red .blue span {color: blue;}
```

OR

```
.blue span {
    color: blue !important;
}
```

OR for "flexibility"

```
#red .blue span, .blue span, #someotherID .blue span {color: blue;}
```

OR something as horrid as this

```
var id = $("#red");
id.addClass(id.attr("id")).removeAttr("id");
```

Comment: I thought about this as well, however the problem is that it doesn't satisfy the "without otherwise restricting the parent style" part. See [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/f4ke2/3/)

Comment: In that case you simply do #red .blue span {color: blue;} in most real life scenarios this is what you do anyways. Cascading is the keyword.

Comment: Then I run into flexibility issues (see OP and comments on @ExplosionPills answer). It seems there may not be a way to do this with my current dom.

Comment: For your flexibility issue do this: #red .blue span, .blue span {color: blue;}

Comment: There could be more ID-styled elements above where the `.blue` could be than just the `#red`. The `!important` seems like realistically the only way to do this with the flexibility I want without changing my DOM. In my current scenario I think I'll actually go with `#red .blue span` as I am only planning to have `.blue` within `#red`... The question was based more on foreseeable future issues than my current issue... but I suppose I learned a "feature" of styling priority and will have to work around it.

Comment: Though as general practice, I try not use !important at all, and structure css in a way that I don't need to force rules with !. But these are personal preferences...

Comment: You can also change framework so it outputs classes instead of IDs. Or you can rewrite them with jquery :)

Comment: Yea I think I'm going to have it (back end) add a class (but also keep the ID), I'll style based on the class. Not a fan of changing the dom onload with js.

Comment: Note though, you will still have problem with .green.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using style sheets (in a framework or otherwise) that assign properties to elements by class, i.e. using class selectors, you simply have to take this into account when writing other CSS rules. So this is a matter of disciplined coding (HTML and CSS), not about using some trick to get rid of normal CSS principles.

Basically, set properties only on those elements that you want to have affected, without using selectors with too wide coverage. Say, if you want to set the text inside some element red, set `color: red` on that element only, not on its descendants, unless you really want to override whatever settings they might have.

For example, if there is a style sheet with `.foo { color: blue }`, then this will affect any element in class `foo`, unless overridden by another rule, as per the CSS cascade. So if you don’t want it to be overridden in a situation like `<div id=xxx>...<span class=foo>...</span>...</div>`, you just can’t set `#xxx span { color: red }`, because then you would override the rule, by virtue of a more specific selector. Using `#xxx { color: red }` would be safe in this sense, since the `span` (having its color set) will not inherit its parent’s color.

Using `!important` as in `.foo { color: blue !important }` might seem to solve the problem, but `!important` makes style sheets difficult to manage and maintain. It also creates problems when you need a tool for overriding the effect of specificity but can’t, because you’ve already fired the weapon. The rule `.foo { color: blue !important }` is not effective against `#xxx span { color: red !important }`.